# Unknown Syntax in file

Tags: angularjs, syntax, gruntjs

I am currently working on someone else's codebase and I have encountered this:

```
<!-- compiled CSS --><% styles.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=appRoot%>/<%= file %>" /><%});%>

<!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=appRoot%>/<%= file %>"></script><% }); %>

</head>
<body data-version="<%=version%>">
```

I am sure its related to the grunt build but I need to understand the importance of using EJS in this implementation.

Comment: What is your question? Is it about an error? If so you need to include the error message and anything else about the error that could help pin point what/where/why it is occurring. The only thing I see here is some code with either an old asp MVC syntax or asp.net binding syntax.

Comment: The question is just what is that syntax and what is it doing? I don't think its asp at all its all angular based with a grunt build. I think its 'ngBoilerPlate' syntax but I am unsure.

Comment: What is the file type?

Comment: I think it could be Asp.Net. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/957321/1260204. If the file type is .aspx or .ascx then this is probably the case.

Comment: this is embedded in an index.html file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908311/how-do-i-add-auto-generated-list-of-files-in-a-directory-to-a-js-file

Answer (score 0):

So it is actually syntax from ng-boilerplate.

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp